# installation ubuntu 14.04 on win Xp professional 32 bit

Tags: system-installation

I have an old Win XP Professional 32-bit machine. Intel Pentium(R) 4 CPU 2,4 GHz and 1,25GB RAM. When I try to install Ubuntu 14.04 from DVD I get this message: This kernel required an x86-64CPU, but only detected on i 686CPU unable to boot please use a kernel appropriate for your CPU. What can i do?

Comment: I sounds like you've downloaded the 64bit Ubuntu.  You need to download and install the [32bit Ubuntu](http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04.1/ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-i386.iso).

Comment: Mitch is right. My answer is provided that 32 bit is the one you are using and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Your processor only supports 32bit operating systems.

You need to download a [32bit Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/contribute/?version=14.04.1&architecture=i386) version as @Mitch stated in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

You may have a setting called Intel Virtualization Technology or AMD V, for those respective boards. Enable this setting.

Where can you enable it from? Its in the BIOS. Browse around, find Virtualization Technology/V and enable it. Restart and try again. You should be good to go.

Hope this helps.